# on the definition of half-open intervals in Munkres' topology book

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I'm reading Munkres' topology, and I came across his definitin of half-open intervals, In which he states : [a, b) = {x | a ≤ x < b} such that a < b. My question is : Why is this extra condition necessary? why does he have to add that a < b? Why isn't this condition added to the definition of open intervals, but only to half-open intervals?

Comment: If we neglect that condition, then we will get an empty set.  Perhaps, in context, he wants to exclude the empty set?  Or perhaps he is concerned that people will read $[a,b)$ as "the points between a and b, including a and excluding b", which makes sense and is non-empty even when b<a, but which would then include the right endpoint instead of the left endpoint, and in some examples it is important that you are including only the left endpoints.  This mistake is innocuous for open intervals or closed intervals, but devastating for half open intervals.

Comment: I found definitions of $(a,b)$ on p. 25 and  p. 84. Here Munkres requires $a < b$. Is there another definition in his book?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a=b$. Then $[a,b)=\{ x\in\mathbb{R} | a\leq x <a\}=\emptyset$.

The same happens if you take $(a,b)$, but (by my opinion) since it is used more often, we usually skip that condition.